# Method to find selection operation in UItextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I have an `UITextView` that I want to detect both the starting and end of the selection operation.

`- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(TextView *)textView`

get triggered even while user drag the selection pointer to change the selection. But I want to know the end point of selection operation(i.e Drag end).

Could anyone help me?

Thanks for your answers..